# Why doesn't path.abspath generate the dependency library's absolute path?

Tags: python

My project A depends on another project B, in which I need to load resources, which are stored in text file.

In project B, initially, I used relative file path to load the text file:

```
extractors/lexicon/video/actor.txt
```

However, when I run my project, it complains that the file 'actor.txt' can not be found. Then I tried to use absolute path by doing:

```
os.path.abspath("extractors/lexicon/video/actor.txt")
```

And then I ran my project A. The problem was that it generated the root path of my own project , then concatenated with the relative path in project B. Still, the program can't find the file.

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: you could use `__file__` to generate real path for folder in project B and use it to create real paths for files in project B.

Comment: `HOME_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` `path = os.path.join(HOME_FOLDER, "extractors/lexicon/video/actor.txt")`

Comment: or use `sys.argv[0]` instead of `__file__`. Code is the same. `__file__` may not works if you run in some Shells (IDLE, ipython), [Python 101: How to Find the Path of a Running Script](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/10/29/python-101-how-to-find-the-path-of-a-running-script/)